# Convert column of years in long dataframe to wide format, with the minimal year of every ID in a column, the second minmal year in the 2nd column etc

Tags: r

this is my first ever question here so I hope I will format it the right way. It's about R. My question is this:

I have a dataframe that contains the following info:

| ID | Thing | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2024 |
| 1 | Car | 2028 |
| 2 | House | 2024 |
| 2 | House | 2026 |
| 2 | House | 2027 |

Etc.

I need this dataframe in the following format:

| ID | Thing | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2024 | 2028 | NA |
| 2 | House | 2024 | 2026 | 2027 |

How would I go about this? I tried to pivot from long to wide but then I got this:

| ID | Thing | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2024 | NA | NA |
| 1 | Car | NA | 2028 | NA |
| 2 | House | 2024 | NA | NA |
| 2 | House | NA | 2026 | NA |
| 2 | House | NA | NA | 2027 |

I tried splitting up the dataframe by selecting the individual years and then joining those new dataframes but then I got this:

| ID | Thing | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2024 | NA | NA | 2028 |
| 2 | House | 2024 | 2026 | 2027 | NA |

And now I've ran out of ideas. Part of the problem is probably I don't know how to describe this conceptually so that makes it hard to Google... Help?

Comment: Add an id number to your rows within groups and then pivot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arise from the fact that you don't have a variable indicating a common id within groups, i.e. to create the wide variables, they have to share a naming pattern. You can do that by adding a row number id within groups:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(row_n = row_number(), .by = ID) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "row_n", values_from = "Year", names_prefix = "Year")

# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#      ID Thing Year1 Year2 Year3
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1 Car    2024  2028    NA
# 2     2 House  2024  2026  202
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with base R, you can try `reshape`

```
reshape(
    transform(
        df,
        time = ave(Year, ID, FUN = seq_along)
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = c("ID", "Thing"),
    timevar = "time"
)
```

which gives

```
  ID Thing Year.1 Year.2 Year.3
1  1   Car   2024   2028     NA
3  2 House   2024   2026   2027
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Thing = c("Car", "Car",
"House", "House", "House"), Year = c(2024L, 2028L, 2024L, 2026L,
2027L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```